# Cloud software for floor planning

Tags: cross-platform, cloud-service, planning

I have an apartment plan which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to import this picture into some dedicated software and be able to annotate it, put some furniture on it, etc.

If there is no such cloud software, please recommend me something for the following platforms (preferably cross-platform though): Linux, Windows, Mac OS X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know a cloud based software for this, but have used [SweetHome3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/) (Java, so all platforms) and found it good.

You can't upload that image into it as far as I know, but building the walls is an easy task (I did it in under 30 minutes, including the learning curve).

You can then place the furniture from their stock images onto your floor plan and get a 3D perspective on it. That way you can not only measure if it would fit, but actually get an impression on how it would look.

I don't have the program anymore since my flat is now in a completed state so I can't share my own screenshots. I will give some from their [gallery](http://www.sweethome3d.com/gallery.jsp).

The program is available in a huge set of languages, I've used the German version.

The only downside I found was that the rooms seemed more crammed in the program than in reality, but I don't know if that is due to different perspectives.

Floor Plan:
[image: Floor Plan]

Top View:
[image: Top View]

3D Interior
[image: 3D Interior]

3D Exterior
[image: 3D Exterior]

Answer (score 0):

You can paste a JPG/image into Draw.io/app.diagram.net and draw over it, using basic floor plan shapes. I've added some air conditioner split systems to my floor plan layer (JPG, pasted):
[image]